# Handling two files with varying delimination Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, delimiter

I want to take two text files and write/append them into a single file. Each file has a different delimiter. Is there a way to easily detect delimination? Or an easy way to handle this situation? How to handle unknown file delimination?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "delimiter", what do you mean? Line endings?

Comment: What do you mean by delimiter? Can you show an example of what you have tried and how it is not working as you'd like?

Comment: By delimiter I mean character(s) that separates values (so a comma or tab or space etc.) So some files are comma delimited, some tab delimited, etc. When I create one file from two files some text looks like: BHC0124-BS1 LCS WQ BS other text looks like "Blank","WQ","LB","Lab","", The first text file is tab delimited, the second is comma delimited.

Comment: So they're CSV files, not plain text files?

Comment: And what is the result you would like to get? And what was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: They are .txt files.

Comment: @mkriger1 I want a single text file from two text files and the single file will have the same deliminator for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to determine an unspecified delimiter.  In fact, one can easily construct pathological cases in which the delimiter is ambiguous.

However, there's hope from the examples you give.  It appears that your fields are primarily alphanumeric data -- sometimes including hyphens, quotation marks, etc. -- separated by common punctuation.  You could read a few lines of the file and determine a likely delimiter from the textual characteristics.

Identify and collapse alphanum fields to a single character, such as `A`.  From the remaining characters, look for one that more-or-less alternates with those fields.  Work with a prioritized consideration list, such as (tab, comma, space, ...) and compute some goodness of fit until you get a figure that looks likely.  Use that as the delimiter to read the file.

Once you have the lines of each file properly ingested, writing the file with the `csv` package is simple (see online examples).